# Android Studio - Drawer Toggle of the Toolbar not Opening the Drawer

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, navigation-drawer, android-togglebutton

Anyone know what I am doing wrong why my Drawer Toggle button of my Toolbar is not opening the Navigation Drawer?

I am using the below code inside my `onCreate`

```
        Toolbar toolbar;
        NavigationView mNavigationView;
        DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        /**
         *Setup the DrawerLayout and NavigationView
         */
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navstuff) ;

        /**
         * Setup click events on the Navigation View Items.
         */

        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                ...
                return false;
            }
        });

        /**
         * Setup Drawer Toggle of the Toolbar
         */

        ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout, toolbar,R.string.app_name,
                R.string.app_name);
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

and I have the below code for my `activity_main.xml`

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_rl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/tabs_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/shitstuff"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
    app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I want to add a `Navigation Drawer` with my CollapsingToolbarLayout. but the Toggle button is not opening the Drawer. Also the CollapsingToolbarLayout sometimes is not scrolling up. I am using the `minSdkVersion 21` for my project.

Comment: I would guess it's because your `DrawerLayout` isn't actually on-screen. It's being pushed out because the `ViewPager` is filling the parent `View`. Move the `ViewPager` to inside the `DrawerLayout`, above the `NavigationView`.

Comment: thanks mike. but how about the toggle button?

Comment: That's what I was saying. I think it just looks like your toggle isn't working because the drawer isn't on-screen. Can you open it by dragging? Either way, the setup you have it now isn't really how you use a `DrawerLayout`.

Comment: yes i can open the drawer by dragging.

Comment: OK, then your `DrawerLayout` is covering everything, so you can't click on the `Toolbar`. If you want the drawer over everything, make the `DrawerLayout` the root `View` of your layout, and put the `CoordinatorLayout` inside it as the first child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just end up Creating 3 xml file for `activity_main`, `app_bar` and `content_main`

**app_bar**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
            android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

**content_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/tabs_viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:title="" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/mystuff"
            app:menu="@menu/drawermenu" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I just run without doing anything in my `ActivityMain class` but it's works. I'm still working on this, hope there's no bug comes.